# Tomcat error when deploying my play Framework

Tags: tomcat, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a play framework project https://github.com/nstreltsov/aplana-personal

First I added `play2war` plugin. Generate `war` file completed successfully and
I copied my `war` file to tomcat `webapps` folder and renamed it to `ROOT.war` then I started Tomcat and Go to vy localhost http://localhost:8084/ but the page was empty.

Please help me

There was this exception in Tomcat log:

```
08-Aug-2015 22:54:22.497 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class play.core.server.servlet25.Play2Servlet
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.core.server.servlet25.Play2Servlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you have a web.xml in WEB-INF? Which version of play are you using? Which version of play2war are you using? Which Play2WarKeys.servletVersion have you set?

Comment: use play framework 2.4.2, play2war 1.4-beta1, war file have web.xml,
my build.sbt have Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "3.0",
my war my-files.ru/9ouau4/ROOT.war

Comment: web.xml
<listener> <listener-class>play.core.server.servlet25.Play2Servlet</listener-class> </listener> <servlet> <servlet-name>play</servlet-name> <servlet-class>play.core.server.servlet25.Play2Servlet</servlet-class> </servlet> <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>play</servlet-name> <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>

Comment: update: i use play 2.4.0

Comment: i delete web.xml and build war. After run tomcat have error: catalina.log INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\org.apache.tomcat.tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.21.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Comment: localhost.log SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class play.core.server.servlet30.Play2Servlet
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.typesafe.config.ConfigException)

Comment: I suspect that 'Unsupported major.minor version 52.0' means you have compiled to java 1.8 bytecode, but are running tomcat7; either recompile to 1.7 bytecode or use tomcat8

Comment: yes, i'm use tomcat 7. Now I tried tomcat 8 and it work!

Comment: How can I note that you have decided my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the error

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class play.core.server.servlet25.Play2Servlet
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.core.server.servlet25.Play2Servlet
```

This can be caused by including a web.xml within your WEB-INF directory, if you are using play2war with `servletVersion` 3.0.

The follow on issue you experienced:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.typesafe.config.ConfigException)
```

Is thrown when a jvm below version 1.8 attempts to run 1.8 bytecode. I can see you are running tomcat7; try running your war with tomcat8, or alternatively if you need to use tomcat7 recompile your code as 1.7 bytecode